# ModelForm: upload file in chunks in custom path

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following situation:

- models.py

  ```
  class ShapeFile(models.Model):
      name = models.SlugField()
      file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)

  def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
      return os.path.join("my","custom","path",filename)
  ```
- views.py

  ```
  def shapeIng(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
  ```

In this way, is the file uploaded automatically chunked?
If not I would like to chunk it so , as suggested in the docs, I've tried with the following

- models.py

  ```
  from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

  class ShapeFile(models.Model):
      name = models.SlugField()
      file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)

  def get_upload_path_2(filename):
     return os.path.join(default_storage.path(''),"my","custom",
         "path","%s" % filename)
  ```
- views.py

  ```
  from os import makedirs
  form os.path import dirname
  from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

  def shapeIng(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():

              # Split uploaded file into chunks
              fileName = request.FILES['file']
              filePath = get_upload_path_2(fileName)
              handle_uploaded_file(fileName, filePath) # Uploads the file

              form.save() # Uploads the file again!!!

  def handle_uploaded_file(fileName, filePath):
      makedirs(dirname(filePath))
      with open(filePath, 'wb+') as destination:
          for chunk in fileName.chunks():
              destination.write(chunk)
  ```

It works but **the file get stored twice** with names compliant with Django docs, for example *myFile.zip* and *myFile_1.zip*. The one stored with `save()` I'm not sure if it is chunked or not.
Could you please explain to me if chunking is automatic in a ModelForm and maybe give me a working example?
Have I to redefine the `save()` method in order to store normally the "name" field and to chunk the "file" field?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by file is automatically chunked? Django will always give you full uploaded file.

Comment: I mean what described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files). I want the file sent completely of course, but with chunks as described in the docs you save memory.

Comment: This is not while uploading the file, but after its uploaded how you can read the file.

Comment: Ok and what about my question about saving the file twice? I would like to avoid the `save()` one and maintain only the one performed by my `handle_uploaded_file()`...

Comment: Your `handle_uploaded_file()` seems redundant as saving of uploaded file is handled by django through `form.save()`

Comment: So there are no performance disadvantages uploading and storing the file with `save()` method?

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I will maintain the `save()` approach because is easier.